# Is it possible to style columnrange highchart to change color when data is below 0?

Tags: highcharts

im working on columrange highchart and I want to style it thats when it reach 0 it changes color for a little lighter. Is it possible ? Also would like to include xAxis categories into highchart. Thats what i got for now: `http://jsfiddle.net/kt6wyc5b/'

Thats what i want to achieve `http://imgur.com/VBfnywO "highchart"`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use plotBands with proper zIndex and then set transparent white color.

```
plotBands: [{ 
                zIndex:7,
                color: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.4)',
                from: -20,
                to: 0
}],
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/vq7bwu2r/

Comment: Yeah it interferes with tooltip, but that was mostly what i was looking for. Thanks ! Oh and is it possible to make 0 in the center like in the image ?

Comment: Yes, by setting min value on Axis.